# How to display the user Avatar on all templates (django) i use base.html

Tags: django, django-templates

Hello everyone I want  to finish my project using django
The problem  in how to make avatar image appear on all project templates

If an avatar is displayed in one template, for exemple: www.site.com/index
 the other does not work www.site.com/page2/page3......
help me please cz i get tired for this

here is my `model.py`

```
 class author(models.Model):

   name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   profile_picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='Avatar')


   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

 class articles(models.Model):
    article_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ForeignKey(author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`base.html`

```
    <!-- when loggedin -->
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <li class="nav-item dropdown my-2">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" href="" id="themes" > {{full_name}}  <span class="caret"></span>
        <img class="rounded-circle"  src="{{ user.author.profile_picture.url }}" style="max-width: 2em; margin-right: 10px;"> </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="themes">

          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/profile/">profile</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/create/" >add post</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="margin-top: 1em;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">logOut</a>             
           </div>
       </li>
   {% else %}
   <!-- end loggedin -->
```

views.py

```
   # open home page
   def index(request):
       authorUser = get_object_or_404(author, name=request.user.id)
       all_articles = articles.objects.all().order_by('-id')

       solo = articles.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]
       solo1 = articles.objects.order_by('-id')[:3]
       #show five articles plus read
       article_read = articles.objects.order_by('id')[:5]
       #show spicial articles
       # show first article
       first = articles.objects.order_by('-id')[:10]

       # show fourth articles
       fourth = articles.objects.order_by('-id')[:4]


       return render(request, 'home/index.html', {
                                      'full_name': request.user.username, 
                                       'first_article':first, 
                                       'fourth_article':fourth, 
                                       'all_articles': all_articles, 
                                       'five_articles': article_read, 
                                       'solo': solo, 
                                       'solo1': solo1,
                                       'user': authorUser
                                     })
```

Comment: You can simply use `request.user.author.profile_picture.url` in all of your templates.

Comment: base.html conten navbar and footer but other templates does not contain navbar end footer

Comment: @Selcuk no you can't, it's a foreignkey from author to user so you would have to do `request.user.author_set.first.profile_picture.url`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You are absolutely right. The models seem a bit weird in that case as `get_object_or_404` would fail when there are more than one `author` instances for the same user. I would suggest changing it to a `OneToOne` relation instead of a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Thank you now it works  Daniel Roseman

Comment: i just remove this viriable.... authorUser = get_object_or_404(author, name=request.user.id) and it fixed thank you

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img class="rounded-circle" src="{{ request.user.author.profile_picture.url }}" style="max-width: 2em; margin-right: 10px;"></img>
```

you need to include `request`